# Getting duplicate values while appending cleaned data to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

I have a txt file and I need to extract some values and organize as dictionary.
Here is the needed format! `{State: Town}`

for example `{'Alabama': 'Auburn', Alabama: 'Florence'....'Wyoming': 'Laramie'}`

Here is my code:

```
with open('my.txt') as file:
    output = []
    current_state = ""
    region = ""
    for line in file:
        if (len(line.split("[edit]")) == 2):
            current_state = line.split("[edit]")[0]
        else:
            region = line.split(" (")[0]
        if (region != ""):
            output.append([current_state, region])
    return output
```

However, my code doesn't do what I want it to do. It feels as I'm storing previously extracted "region" value and appending it to the next state. So there is something wrong with the logic and I'm not sure what exactly.

```
[['Alabama', 'Auburn'],
 ['Alabama', 'Florence'],
 ['Alabama', 'Jacksonville'],
 ['Alabama', 'Livingston'],
 ['Alabama', 'Montevallo'],
 ['Alabama', 'Troy'],
 ['Alabama', 'Tuscaloosa'],
 ['Alabama', 'Tuskegee'],
 ['Alaska', 'Tuskegee'],
 ['Alaska', 'Fairbanks'],
 ['Arizona', 'Fairbanks'],
 ['Arizona', 'Flagstaff'],
 ['Arizona', 'Tempe'],
 ['Arizona', 'Tucson'],...]
```

As you can see I'm getting 'Fairbanks' 2 times, first it is appended to Alaska, which is correct and second it is getting appended to Arizona, which is not correct. I have this happening to all of my states.

```
...
 ['Alaska', 'Fairbanks'],
 ['Arizona', 'Fairbanks'],
...
 ['Wisconsin', 'Whitewater'],
 ['Wyoming', 'Whitewater'],
 ['Wyoming', 'Laramie']]
```

Comment: You're using lists, not dictionaries.  Lists use square brackets `[...]`, dicts use curly braces `{...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not reset the region, so it store previous result.

```
if (region != ""):
  output.append([current_state, region])
```

change to

```
if (region != ""):
  output.append([current_state, region])
  region = ''
```

Comment: @lilia  not a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to put the values into a dictionary then,

before `with open('my.txt') as file:`, put `country = dict()`

and inside the loop you can use as

```
if (region != ""):
        output.append([current_state, region])
        if current_state in country:

            country[current_state].append(region)
        else:
            country[current_state] = []
            country[current_state].append(region)
        region = ''
```

For your question the `region = ''` will solve the issue but to put in dictionary the above code will help, this will make a list for a particular key. Happy coding!